# Running the latest .exe in nested folder

Tags: powershell

Previously, I created a script that will find the latest build of a software and install the .msi, now that I have the program installed, I would like to search for the program on my computer and open the .exe.

I believe what is happening, is that the exe I am trying to run is the same name as it is in all the other build folders.

I have tried filtering item through the date in a few different ways. Below is the current code I last tried:

```
$path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Company"
$refDate = (Get-Date).Adddays(-30)
$filter = "app.exe"

&$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter $filter -File -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt $refDate}
```

I would like to run the correct exe from the corresponding folder.

Comment: Remove the ampersand from that last line you have there. `$latest` is an object.. not just a file path. On its _own_ line `& $latest.Fullname`.

Comment: I have the appersand there to run the file that is found. I will try this though.

EDIT: I tried this, but it is still giving errors, because the .exe it finds is in numerous other build folders in the directory.

Comment: How do you decide which one to use then if there are so many? Just the date filter that does not seem sufficient

Comment: So $latest does not contain the lastest but a group of latest. `Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter $filter -File -Recurse  | Sort lastwritetime -Desc | Select -First 1 -Expand Fullname`

Comment: Used this to tweak it, works just as I wanted it to. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's @Matt's answer, integrated into your script.

```
$path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Company"
$refDate = (Get-Date).Adddays(-30)
$filter = "app.exe"

$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter $filter -File -Recurse | Sort lastwritetime -Desc | Select -First 1 -Expand Fullname
& $latest
```

Trying to execute the assignment statement (`& $latest = ...`) instead of the `$latest` variable may have been the cause for the error.

Answer (score 0):

try this (with this method if not executable founded you dont have an error)

```
$path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Company"
$filter = "app.exe"

Get-ChildItem $path -Filter $filter -File -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Sort lastwritetime -Desc | Select -First 1 | %{& $_.FullName}
```